# Is there a way to write self-documenting types in C#?

Tags: c#

If I have, for example a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<int, OrderSummary> _orderSummaries;
```

In C++ I might have:

```
typedef int OrderID;
private Dictionary<OrderID, OrderSummary> _orderSummaries;
```

to show that the dictionary key type is an order ID. Is there an equivalent in C#?

Comment: You could name your dictionary 'orderSummaryById'

Comment: you mean typedefs? no, not really.

Comment: @PaulG - yes naming can help but sometimes it becomes overly cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use a type alias, like this:

```
using OrderId = System.Int32;
```

But that alias will only be valid within *that* source file.
Every other source file would see your dictionary as `Dictionary<int, OrderSummary>`.

This kind of alias is used mostly for disambiguating between types with the same name, not as a substitute of `typedef`. Using it for any purpose other than distinguishing between types with the same name is, IMO, a bad practice and actually hinders readability.

If your `OrderId` really does carry a specific and distinct semantic meaning, I suggest creating your own value type that encapsulates an int.

Comment: -1 although this is possible, you are confusing anybody who is just casually looking at a method in your class to see what it does. "oh he has a class called OrderId? what is that? why does an order id need a class? oh moving the mouse on it doesn't show anything interesting... let's 'go to definition'... etc..."

Comment: @AK_ I *did* put in a disclaimer saying that this is not what type aliases are for, and that they're not used for readability. I was just merely demonstrating the closest C# can get to C++'s typedef. And I also did say that if he wants to create an alias for `int` because his `OrderId` does carry a special meaning, that he should create his own value type that encapsulates an int. Is that wrong?

Comment: My vote is already locked. But I think you should have stressed the point that this is not a common or accepted practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a type alias: `using OrderId = System.Int32;` This is only valid within that source file, so it may not document as fully as you may like...

However, if you want something that documents the intent of your data structure (the dictionary) externally, then I would implement a wrapper class:

```
public class OrderSummaries
{
  private readonly Dictionary<int, OrderSummary> _orderSummaries;

  public OrderSummary FindOrderSummary(int orderId)
  {
    return _orderSummaries[orderId];
  }

  ...
}
```

You could also implment a `struct` that contains a single `System.Int32`:

```
public struct OrderId
{
  public readonly Int32 Id;

  public OrderId(int id)
  {
    Id = id;
  }
}
```

And use `Dictionary<OrderId, OrderSummary>`

Comment: In the first example, I think you mean `public OrderSummary` instead of `public int`.